# Usage of word "those" in an essay

Tags: grammar

I am writing critical analysis essay on philosophical paper. It is an undergraduate 1000 word task.
I have a sentence:

```
(contents of philosophical paper) contradicts with what idea 1, idea 2, and idea3.  
In this essay, (contents of philosophical paper) are analysed based on **those** ideas.
```

Is this a legal move to make in English essay writing? If not, is there any possible alternative phrases/words I can use?

Comment: It's exceedingly difficult to tell what you're talking about.  Are those your words or words from the assignment?

Comment: What is "philosophical paper"? Is it like construction paper?

Comment: @Robusto contents of philosophical paper is what I am doing critical analysis on. It is a proof of an external world.

Comment: @HotLicks This is extraction from the introduction of my essay. Because `turn it in` (the plagiarism detecting software) may detects it as a plagiarism, I changed some words.

Comment: contradicts does not take with....yes, those ideas, since you have already named them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I understand OP's question: he wants help with deciding between "those" and "these."

At Google Books (not vanilla Google), the initial search core

"analyzed based on these ideas"

is found to be too long to generate a significant number of hits, thus we shorten it to:

"analyzed based on **these**"
About 3,720 results

"analyzed based on **those**"
About 144 results

Thus we can conclude that the English-language speakers prefer "**these**," and this is normal to me, as the eventual choices (the three ideas, in this case) are usually brought to be close to the place of the "surgery":-), the analysis.

Comment: The three ideas are indeed mentioned quite near "those" (or "these") in the question, but I suspect that "idea 1" and its brethren were intended to be placeholders for something longer, like descriptions of actual ideas.  If so, then idea 1 might end up quite far from "those" or "these" in the actual paper.

Answer (score -1):

Many people assume that an essay is an ordinary work. However, it is not. The essay is a prosaic literary genre. Translated from French means "sketch". The essay reflects the individual experiences of the author, his views on a particular question. It does not provide an exhaustive answer to a specific question, but reflects one's own opinion or impression. When writing an essay, the logic develops perfectly, the ability to argue one's opinion, and correctly present the information. Style of presentation is more focused on conversational.
To properly [get homework help online](https://maxhomework.com/) should take into account the specific features that distinguish it from other genres. The main features of the essay: The presence of a certain narrow topic that contains a problem and prompts the reader to reflect. Subjective author's position. The essay is distinguished precisely by the presence of an author's view of the existing problem, its relation to the world, speech and thinking. Spoken writing style. It is necessary to avoid complicated formulations, too long sentences. It is important to follow a laid-back style to establish contact with the reader. It is important not to overdo it, turning the essay into a substandard text full of slang. The correct emotional color of the text will be given by short, simple and understandable sentences, the use of different intonations in sentences. A detailed analysis of the problem.

Comment: What word in French means sketch??

Comment: This is not relevant, and it doesn't even begin to answer the question.